# Response from webpage not changing iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

I am using an external library called 'ASIHTTPRequest' that I am using to submit a form that is on a web server through my app. Everything works great and I get the html of the response of the request. The html contains a link I get and I then do another request on that link to get the html of the second request. Heres my problem, when I try and request that link that was in the html (I have stripped it down to just the link, I am positive.) I get the same html response as the first response I got. My code will not format correctly in the page. Here is the code at http://pastie.org

http://pastie.org/3069630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is a misplaced **if**

The `if (i == 1)` branch should not be in the scope of the `if (i == 0)` code. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

There are a few small errors causing your problem here:

1. Your `if (i==1) { … }` statement is nested inside you `if (i==0) { … }` statement (perhaps a mismatched closing bracket is to blame?
2. Your `if (i==1) { … }`, once in the correct spot will want to be `else if (i==0) { … }`

Basically, the first time `requestFinished:` gets called and (`i` is 0) it starts off, adds 1 to `i`, makes the second request, and (still in the first response) checks to see if `i` is 1. `i` will always be 1 there so it pops up the alert view. When the second request finishes it never checks to see if `i` is 1 because that is nested inside the check for `i` being 0.

The reason you’ll want `else if …` is because otherwise the second if-statement will always trigger immediately after the first (because you do `i++`).